# Get NT style domain\user given DN

Tags: active-directory, dns

I have the DN of a user in Active Directory, I want to get the "NT style" domain\user from this. The sAMAccountname AD property gives me the user part, but what about the domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can get it by taking the last part of the user DN (`DC=domain,DC=local`) and adding `CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,` before.

Then do a subtree search for `(&(nCName="DC=domain,DC=local")(nETBIOSName=*))` with `CN=Partitions, CN=Configuration, DC=domain, DC=local` as the starting point; the entry you get back will have the NETBIOS name of the domain in the `nETBIOSName`-attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. However, I am guaranteed to only get ONE value for this search?

Comment: If you have multiple domains in your forrest, you'll need to include the domain you're after in your search; I've modified my reply to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

How about using --> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.ToString()

See msdn info about it here: [NTAccount.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.ntaccount.tostring(VS.80).aspx)

This should return a string in the format of domain\user... is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this conversion is through the [DsCrackNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675970(VS.85).aspx) API.  You specify the input format and output format and it does the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **PowerShell** code:

```
$hash = @{} //this contains the map of CN and nCNAME
$Filter = '(nETBIOSName=*)'
$RootOU = "CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" //Change this to your org's domain
$Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"
$Searcher.Filter = $Filter
$Searcher.SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$($RootOU)")
$Searcher.FindAll()|sort | foreach { $hash[($_.Properties.ncname).Trim()] = ($_.Properties.cn).Trim() }
$hash.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property Value
```

If the user details are available in `$userDetails`, then the you can get the correct domain with this:

```
$hash[[regex]::Match($userDetails.DistinguishedName, 'DC=.*').Value]
```

and the final username would look like this:

```
$hash[[regex]::Match($userDetails.DistinguishedName, 'DC=.*').Value] + "\" + $userDetails.SamAccountName
```