# How to get Domain from GroupPrincipal?

Tags: .net, active-directory

I need to list all users from the specific local group in the following format: "Domain\UserName". I can extract collection of GroupPrincipal objects for the group, but I don't know how to get users in required format. GroupPrincipal doesn't have property Domain.

The following code outputs users without domain (e.g. "UserName").

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, null))
{
    using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, @"My Local Group"))
    {
        if (group != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in group.GetMembers(false))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get domain netbios name from the principal object? And if so, how to get it?

Comment: Do you really need it in `DOMAIN\UserName` form? Could you also accept `User@Domain`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I need username in the same form as it's returned by HttpContext.User.Identity.Name with enabled Windows authentication (DOMAIN\UserName).

Comment: `p` exposes a SID property, which gives you the security identifier. Similarly, the Identity exposes a User property (if suitably cast to a WindowsIdentity object), which is also a security identifier. Could you not do a comparison based on those?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The purpose is not to compare the users. I need some kind of auto completion on the web form for a user field. It's a free text and suggestions should be obtained from the group.

Comment: the purpose *must* be for a comparison at some point, otherwise the formatting wouldn't matter to you. Whether it's happening immediately in the above code, or at a later point, it's still wrong. You should compare windows accounts based on SIDs, not based on the string form of the username - account names can change.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Lets suppose it's a legacy system and I can't change the existing behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the domain details from the principal's Context.  e.g.:

```
foreach (var p in group.GetMembers(false))

    {
        Console.Write(p.SamAccountName);
        if (p.ContextType == ContextType.Domain)
        {
            Console.Write(" ({0})", p.Context.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

If you just want to output account names in the "domain\user" format from a machine on the domain, you can translate the principal's SecurityIdentifier to an NTAccount.  e.g.:

```
foreach (var p in group.GetMembers(false))
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure of that ! the Name attribut is the same as the first dc attribut, but is it ALL the time the Netbios name of the Domain? Remember that a different Domain Netbios name can be choosen during installation. This is supposed to work most of the time, but not sure the answer

Comment: Yep, principal's context gives me a different name. In my case it's in form 'location.company.com', but I expect 'LOCATION'.

Comment: @JPBlanc: Use of the name was just an example.  OP stated that he wanted to get "domain info" from the principal, but wasn't explicit about what information was desired.

Comment: For me 'p.Sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount))' give an exception here 'System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException'

Comment: @JPBlanc: Does the group you're running against perhaps contain a "stale" member (one for which you see only the SID when you look at the group membership via the Windows UI)?

Comment: I make all my test from a machine outside the domain, that's why I've got the 'IdentityNotMappedException'. Tested from a machine inside the domain IT WORKS (can you edit you answer and add it as comment).

Comment: @JPBlanc: I've added a caveat to the answer regarding the machine being on the domain.

Comment: UserPrincipal.Sid.Translate is very useful

Answer (score 0):

On a pure LDAP, the way to retreive the Netbios Name of a domain partition is the following (given that I'am working on the DC=dom,dc=fr partition) :

```
/* Connection to Active Directory
 */
DirectoryEntry deConf = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=dom,DC=fr", "user", "password");

/* Directory Search
 */
DirectorySearcher dsLookForNetb = new DirectorySearcher(deConf);
dsLookForNetb.Filter = "(nCName=dc=dom,dc=fr)";
dsLookForNetb.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForNetb.PropertiesToLoad.Add("nETBIOSName");

SearchResult RefObj = dsLookForNetb.FindOne();

Console.WriteLine(RefObj.Properties["nETBIOSName"][0]);
```