# Get SamAccountName and Domain Name for all users in a AD group

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory

I have the LDAP path `LDAP://ispgh-ij02.mea.test.com/CN=Connect_MEA_Forest_GUID-01,OU=Groups,OU=Connect-People,OU=Global,DC=mea,DC=test,DC=com` to an `AD group`.

I would like to fetch all the users in the `AD group` and the code should fetch the details in minimal time.

I have to retrieve the `domain` and `SamAccountName (Domain\userName)` properties for the available users.

Could you please help?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Active Directory: Get domain name of user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249139/c-sharp-active-directory-get-domain-name-of-user)

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249139/c-sharp-active-directory-get-domain-name-of-user?rq=1) ? The question is the same than yours.