# Cannot get domain name using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get domain name using C# with the below code,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var domainName = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
    Console.WriteLine(domainName);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It prints domain name correctly in domain connected windows 8 machine. But it doesn't print anything in windows server 2012 R2 machine.

How to get domain name in Windows server 2012 machine.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249139/c-sharp-active-directory-get-domain-name-of-user

Comment: Is the server part of the domain? Does it have multiple interfaces? Which one is used in this check? If you disable other LANs, is it solved then?

Comment: @zchpit User domain isn't necessarily network domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I have used this code to get the domain name.  It is accessed through the environmental variables on that machine.

```
string UserDomain = Environment.UserDomainName.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(UserDomain);
```

Perhaps the exception is caused from running it on a server for which the user does not have the appropriate permissions.  Have you tried doing a "run As administrator" or "run as different user" with the exe?

Comment: I have tried with Administrator too. But it is not working. I have tried to getting from environmental variable already. Its working. Is this a correct way to get the domain name?

Comment: Kumar,  A few more things to see if it leads you anywhere:   1) more specifically, have you opened a command prompt and run your exe from that command prompt?  2) I would try running the command "set" to see if returns all the environmental variables and see the values.  3)  Check out the command iCacls. That might help figure what permissions that user has on that server.  4) I think the exception is pointing to some kind of permission/user issue.

Comment: Works only when the current users accout is in same domain like the machine!

Answer (score 1):

I hope that works for you:

```
string domainName = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain().Name;
```

Comment: Wrap it in try/catch because it can throw.

Comment: Yes it should be wrapped with try/catch but I didn't write a method I just gave single line of code.

Comment: Its working. How it works? Why my code doesn't work. Is something wrong in that method.

Comment: Getting the exception: 

**System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The user name or password is incorrect**

Comment: I cannot see Windows Server 2012 in supported platforms [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getipglobalproperties(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Where do you get that exception? In your method?

Comment: I am getting this exception when trying your code. I am trying to run the code as windows service. But If i use the code normally, i can get the domain name.

Comment: What is the ServiceAccount of Windows service? Is it LocalSystem?